# Create a csv file in python without using csv header

Tags: python, csv

How to create a csv file in python without using import csv. I have all the data in lists. Each row is a list.

Comment: 1. Is this homework? 2. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

How about using pandas?

```
import pandas
df_list = pd.DataFrame(list ) # creating data frame with the list
df_list.to_csv('list.csv') # your csv of the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample dataset and the solution corresponding to it:

Sample data (here each list is a row of the final data frame):

```
data1=['John',27,'Boston','Phd']
data2=['Sophie',24,'California','Msc']
```

Converting to data frame and csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1).T #Transposing
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2).T #Transposing

df_final=pd.concat([df1,df2])

df_final.columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Course'] #Adding column names
print(df_final)

df_final.to_csv(list_final.csv)
```

Output

```
Name    Age City    Course
0   John    27  Boston  Phd
0   Sophie  24  California  Msc
```

In this way you can concat as many `lists` into `dataframe` and convert them into `.csv`

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if it resolved the problem